# refactoring too many parameter in java code

Tags: java, refactoring

I want to refactor the program below. It has too many parameter smell. How can I refactor it?

```
package net.sourceforge.ganttproject.export;

import net.sourceforge.ganttproject.GanttExportSettings;
import net.sourceforge.ganttproject.task.TaskContainmentHierarchyFacade;
import net.sourceforge.ganttproject.resource.HumanResourceManager;
import java.io.File;

public class PDFExportData extends ProjectExportData {

    final String myStylesheet;

public PDFExportData(GanttExportSettings myExportSettings, File myOutputFile, String myProjectName, String myProjectDescription, String myOrganization, HumanResourceManager myResourceManager, TaskContainmentHierarchyFacade myTaskHierarchyFacade, GanttChartExportProcessor myGanttChartExportProcessor, ResourceChartExportProcessor myResourceChartExportProcessor, String stylesheet) {
        super(myExportSettings, myOutputFile, myProjectName, myProjectDescription, myOrganization, myResourceManager, myTaskHierarchyFacade, myGanttChartExportProcessor, myResourceChartExportProcessor);

        myStylesheet = stylesheet;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case I would suggest [Builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) pattern. It is easy to implement in java. It helps to encapsulate the creation process of an object. Just declare `PDFExportData` constructor as `private` (for convenience) and add `PDFExportDataBuilder` static class in it.

Here is an example:

```
public class PDFExportData extends ProjectExportData {

    final String myStylesheet;

    public static class PDFExportDataBuilder {

        private GanttExportSettings myExportSettings;
        private File myOutputFile;
        private String myProjectName;
        private String myProjectDescription;
        private String myOrganization;
        private HumanResourceManager myResourceManager;
        private TaskContainmentHierarchyFacade myTaskHierarchyFacade;
        private GanttChartExportProcessor myGanttChartExportProcessor;
        private ResourceChartExportProcessor myResourceChartExportProcessor;
        private String stylesheet;

        public PDFExportDataBuilder setMyExportSettings(GanttExportSettings myExportSettings) {
            this.myExportSettings = myExportSettings;
            return this;
        }

        public PDFExportDataBuilder setMyOutputFile(File myOutputFile) {
            this.myOutputFile = myOutputFile;
            return this;
        }

        public PDFExportDataBuilder setMyProjectName(String myProjectName) {
            this.myProjectName = myProjectName;
            return this;
        }

        public PDFExportDataBuilder setMyProjectDescription(String myProjectDescription) {
            this.myProjectDescription = myProjectDescription;
            return this;
        }

        public PDFExportDataBuilder setMyOrganization(String myOrganization) {
            this.myOrganization = myOrganization;
            return this;
        }

        public PDFExportDataBuilder setMyResourceManager(HumanResourceManager myResourceManager) {
            this.myResourceManager = myResourceManager;
            return this;
        }

        public PDFExportDataBuilder setMyTaskHierarchyFacade(TaskContainmentHierarchyFacade myTaskHierarchyFacade) {
            this.myTaskHierarchyFacade = myTaskHierarchyFacade;
            return this;
        }

        public PDFExportDataBuilder setMyGanttChartExportProcessor(GanttChartExportProcessor myGanttChartExportProcessor) {
            this.myGanttChartExportProcessor = myGanttChartExportProcessor;
            return this;
        }

        public PDFExportDataBuilder setMyResourceChartExportProcessor(ResourceChartExportProcessor myResourceChartExportProcessor) {
            this.myResourceChartExportProcessor = myResourceChartExportProcessor;
            return this;
    }

        public PDFExportDataBuilder setStylesheet(String stylesheet) {
            this.stylesheet = stylesheet;
            return this;
        }

        public PDFExportData create() {
            return new PDFExportData(this);
        }
    }

    private PDFExportData(PDFExportData.PDFExportDataBuilder b) {
        super(b.myExportSettings, b.myOutputFile, b.myProjectName, b.myProjectDescription, b.myOrganization, b.myResourceManager, b.myTaskHierarchyFacade, b.myGanttChartExportProcessor, b.myResourceChartExportProcessor);

        myStylesheet = b.stylesheet;
    }
}
```

And after this the instantiation is quiet easy and not so *smelly*:

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

```
    PDFExportData pdf = new PDFExportData.PDFExportDataBuilder()
            .setMyExportSettings(new GanttExportSettings())
            .setMyGanttChartExportProcessor(new GanttChartExportProcessor())
            .setMyGanttChartExportProcessor(new GanttChartExportProcessor())
            /// ....
            .create();
}
```

In this case you have to be sure to pass all the required parameters to the builder.

As an alternative you can create some `Bundle` which stores all the values that have to be passes to the `PDFExportData` constructor.